# Can't able to add items from admin (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product, product-attribute, admin-login

I'm getting this below screen when I login into the **admin panel(Magento 2.1.1)** from `India` but this works good when we login from the `UK`.

This issue occurs after we `moved the server from the US to UK`.

When asked the host, they tried troubleshooting and told to uninstall unwanted extensions and this issue persists after uninstalling unused extensions(only in India).

When we login into admin `Products > Catalog` this (attached) screen appears.

Also, the admin panel freezes when we choose more than **3** attributes.

Please help me identify the issue.

[image: Admin Issue after login]

Comment: Have you checked Magento log files? If you're developer then check browser console maybe it will help you.